# Auto update packges in an python exe file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So, i have an exe file based on python, in this file i used the selenium library and i need auto update this library in exe file, any suggestions? Because this file will go a others people that not are programmers. I tested the "os" library, but is not going on the waited

Comment: what is your version of selenium? The latest version v4.6.0 or above has a [SeleniumManager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) class that can download and manage the browser drivers for you,After upgrading selenium you can create exe file. Which may solve your problem of upgrading exe.

Comment: actually I need an automatic update in the exe file that doesn't require a manipulation in the code, something that makes the exe update selenium by itself